# javascript regex look behind to replace a character

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I have a long strings of code that look something like

`hs2^&#x0200;_^HELLO_x_fs2^&#x0200;_^WORLD_x_gn3^&#x0200;_^HOME_x_gs3^&#x0200;…`

I need to do a replace.  A hex character is used repeatedly `&#x0200;` and there’s always a `^` in front of it.  I need to change the number that appears before each `^&#x0200;`    Reduce those numbers by 1. So the final result will be…

`hs1^&#x0200;_^HELLO_x_fs1^&#x0200;_^WORLD_x_gn2^&#x0200;_^HOME_x_gs2^&#x0200;…`

I’m really only dealing with two numbers here, 2 or 3, so the code would read something like this…

`If (any number directly before ^&#x0200; ==2) change it to 1
else if (any number directly before ^&#x0200; ==3) change it to 2`

I’ve heard of something called a “lookback” or “look behind” is that what’s needed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a callback function, which will be used to replace each occurrence using your own logic:

```js
var str = "hs2^&#x0200;_^HELLO_x_fs2^&#x0200;_^WORLD_x_gn3^&#x0200;_^HOME_x_gs3^&#x0200;";
var res = str.replace(/\d(?=\^&#x0200;)/g, num => --num);

console.log(res);
```

In the regex above, you'll notice this: `(?=...)`. It's a positive lookahead, as suggested by @revo. It allows you to match `^&#x0200;`, but avoid passing it to your callback function. Only the digit (`\d`) will be passed, and thus, replaced.

Comment: You could eliminate `substr` call using a positive lookahead.

Comment: @revo Indeed, that makes it even simpler! Thanks

Comment: @CheeseFlavored I edited my answer to reflect that change